# javascript ndefREADER doesn't load automatically

Tags: javascript, nfc

First of all, I have to say this is my first question on stack ;)

I am trying to implement a reading via NFC on my test web, but i dunno why, the ndefReader doesn't works on startup, i have to press any field on the web to get it loaded (or asked for permission).

BUT, if i wrote some alerts to check why it doen't reach the function on startup, it works!!! (of course, it show alerts before). I don't know if when I accept the alert, I am interacting with the web and that's why it works, but anyways, I dunno why this happens (I need to click anywhere before starting).

```
function iniciar() {
    document.getElementById("input1").focus();
    //alert("test before"); <--- IF i remove this, it doesnt works
    document.getElementById("input1").addEventListener("blur", async () => {
      try{
        const ndef = new NDEFReader();
        alert("before wait");
        await ndef.scan();
        alert("after wait");
        ndef.addEventListener("readingerror", () => {
          alert("Argh! Cannot read data from the NFC tag. Try another one?");
        });

        ndef.addEventListener("reading", ({ message, serialNumber }) => {
          alert(`> Serial Number: ${serialNumber}`);
          alert(`> Records: (${message.records.length})`);
        });
      } catch (error) {
        alert("Argh! " + error);
      }
    },false);
```

Comment: What Platform and Browser are you using? (As Web NFC you are trying to use only works on Android and Chrome as it is experimental)

Comment: That one, chrome 91. It works, but as I said not on window loas

Answer (score 0):

To scan and write to NFC tags, you must first request the "nfc" permission while handling a user gesture (e.g a button click, or in your case the "alert" call). Once handled, the NDEFReader scan() and write() methods trigger a user prompt, **if** access was not previously granted.

Check out https://web.dev/nfc/#security-and-permissions to learn more.

Hopefully https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-nfc/ samples should help you as well.

```js
scanButton.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  console.log("User clicked scan button");

  try {
    const ndef = new NDEFReader();
    await ndef.scan();
    console.log("> Scan started");

    ndef.addEventListener("readingerror", () => {
      console.log("Argh! Cannot read data from the NFC tag. Try another one?");
    });

    ndef.addEventListener("reading", ({ message, serialNumber }) => {
      console.log(`> Serial Number: ${serialNumber}`);
      console.log(`> Records: (${message.records.length})`);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Argh! " + error);
  }
});
```